# Add cell to table based on text in first cell with scripts using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this table...

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="test-class"> 
 <tr> 
  <td rowspan="6">TEST123<script type="text/javascript">if(window.VCompare){VCompare('TEST123', 4);}</script></td>
  <td rowspan="6"><img src="/images/clear1x1.gif" width="5" height="5"></td> 
  <td rowspan="6" background="/images/test.gif"><img src="/images/clear1x1.gif" width="1" height="1"></td>
  <td rowspan="4"><img src="/images/clear1x1.gif" width="5" height="5"></td>
  <td colspan="9"><img src="/images/clear1x1.gif" width="5" height="5"></td>
 </tr> 
</table>
```

I need to get the first cell's value without the script tags, then add a cell before the first cell where I got the text. I've tried things like..

```
var matchtext = "TEST123";
jQuery("tr").each(function() {
 var data = jQuery(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
 var data = jQuery.trim(data);
 if (data == matchtext){
    jQuery(this).before("<td class='testclass' rowspan='6'>test inserted!</td>");
 }
});
```

And looping through the table, but that script is throwing me off.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line:

```
if (data == matchtext){
```

to

```
if (data.match(matchtext)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you log `data` to the firebug console you'd see that the string is "TEST123if(window.VCompare){VCompare('TEST123', 4);}" instead of just "TEST123" because the javascript part counts as text too.

Move that JS part out of the table, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXw9f/2/):

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="test-class"> 
 <tr> 
  <td rowspan="6">TEST123</td>
  <td rowspan="6"><img src="/images/clear1x1.gif" width="5" height="5"></td> 
  <td rowspan="6" background="/images/test.gif"><img src="/images/clear1x1.gif" width="1" height="1"></td>
  <td rowspan="4"><img src="/images/clear1x1.gif" width="5" height="5"></td>
  <td colspan="9"><img src="/images/clear1x1.gif" width="5" height="5"></td>
 </tr> 
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">if(window.VCompare){VCompare('TEST123', 4);}</script>
```

Also your JS code doesn't exactly do as you intended to, working code:

```
var matchtext = "TEST123";
$("tr").each(function() {
 var $this = $(this),
     data = $.trim($this.children(':first-child').text());

 if (data == matchtext){
     $this.prepend("<td class='testclass' rowspan='6'>test inserted!</td>");
 }
});
```